# How do I make this continuous regression?

Tags: matlab

Given the function f(x) = ln(x) with x belonging to [1,e] You must develop an algorithm in matlab that performs the following tasks.

1. Perform the continuous regression of f(x) onto the subspace 〈1, x, x^2〉, using the symbolic tools in Matlab. Plot the result (the function and the fitting).
2. Perform the discrete regression of f onto 〈1, x, x^2〉. For that purpose:

2.1. Introduce as regular sampler of the interval [1, e] using 1000 points. Call this sampler xs.

2.2. Evaluate f(x) on xs, and the basis functions 1, x, x^2 to generate {1, x, x^2, f}.

2.3. Perform the regression of f onto 〈1, x, x^2〉.

2.4. Plot the result (the function and the fitting)

i tried with this but it is not giving the right answer, and it is giving an error in plot(xs, f_values)

```
clear all
close all
clc
syms x

f = log(x);
V = [1 x x^2];
coeffs = V\f;
a0 = coeffs(1);
a1 = coeffs(2);
a2 = coeffs(3);
fitting = a0*1+ a1*x + a2*x^2;
ezplot(f,[1,exp(1)])
hold on
ezplot(fitting,[1,exp(1)])
legend('f(x)','fitting')

xs = linspace(1,exp(1),1000);
linspace(1,exp(1),1000)
f_values = subs(f, x, xs);
basis_1 = ones(1, 1000);
basis_x = xs;
basis_x2 = xs.^2;

V = [basis_1; basis_x; basis_x2];

fitting_values = coeffs(1)*basis_1 + coeffs(2)*basis_x + coeffs(3)*basis_x2;
plot(xs, f_values)
hold on
plot(xs, fitting_values)
legend('f(x)', 'fitting')
```

Comment: Where your homework states `You must develop an algorithm`, the "you" part is usually considered non-transferrable. For debugging help please distil your question down to the _specific_ thing you're stuck with, and include the _complete_ error message. Before doing that you should be using the [debugger](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). It would be good for you to read [how do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Looking solely at your error in `plot(xs, f_values)`:

MATLAB's page for the function [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) shows that when accepting two inputs (in your case, `xs` and `f_values`), they are either `(x, y)`, or `(y, line options)`. But since one of the values you've inputted are based on `x` (a *symbolic* value), it's a symbolic vector. `plot` can't handle symbolic inputs.

I believe the equivalent for syms is [fplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot.html) from the symbolic maths toolbox.